# WiFi internet sharing to ethernet switch

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet, bridge

How do I convert an existing WiFi network to a wired ethernet connection? I'm not just looking for a single connection (i.e. WiFi bridge). The WiFi is coming from a mobile device (internet sharing) with a limited number of clients. It would have to be something like a "bridge-router" combination, with a DHCP server that is independent from the mobile device. Does such a device exist?

Comment: Why can't you use a wifi bridge? Just connect an ethernet switch to the bridge and then all your clients to the switch. Your mobile device has a dhcp server built in. I don't see why you would need another one.

Comment: @SpiderPig Good question. I've had some issues getting an IP address for all ethernet devices, and thought it might be due to the restriction of number of simultaneous wireless connections the mobile device imposes.

Comment: If there is such a restriction - whether imposed by the mobile device or the wifi bridge - you will need a router. You can either connect the router to the bridge or use the router itself as a bridge if it offers that functionality. Alternatively you can also use a Windows PC as a router, i.e. connect the PC to wifi and then enable internet connection sharing. Afterwards you can connect the remaining clients to the PC's ethernet port.

Comment: @SpiderPig Thanks. Does this "router-bridge" mode have a specific name? Do you know which devices support it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such devices exist: basically every home router that has both ethernet ports and wifi can do that. You can get used ones for very cheap, and even new ones are not expensive. It doesn't need to have DSL, but having it doesn't hurt.

Put [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/) on it, then you can configure it with a DHCP server and NAT, if the original firmware doesn't allow you to do so.